# Does anyone know how to fix this error in flutter?

Tags: xcode, flutter, android-studio

I am a flutter beginner, and I am writing my app in Android Studio. When I use the ios simulator to test my app, everything works, but when I tried to test my app on my iphone from Android Studio, I got this error:

> ​​(lldb) 2021-11-01 19:15:35.215559-0400 Runner[6818:2556779] fopen
> failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory) Errors
> found! Invalidating cache...
> [VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(101)] Failed to register
> observatory port with mDNS with error -65555.
> [VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(103)] On iOS 14+, local
> network broadcast in apps need to be declared in the app's Info.plist.
> Debug and profile Flutter apps and modules host VM services on the
> local network to support debugging features such as hot reload and
> DevTools. To make your Flutter app or module attachable and
> debuggable, add a '_dartobservatory._tcp' value to the
> 'NSBonjourServices' key in your Info.plist for the Debug/Profile
> configurations. For more information, see
> https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions

The app shows up on my phone, but I open the app, it automatically quits out. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the same issue when trying to launch the app with XCode ?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

First create a copy of your info plist file (`ios/Runner/Info.plist`) that will be for debug/profile builds only, for example you can name it `ios/Runner/Info-debug.plist`:

[image]

Next modify the xcode settings for the `Runner` target to use the new info plist for debug and profile builds, while keeping the old one for release builds:

[image]

Finally, add the following entries to the `Info-debug.plist` as instructed in the error message:

[image]

(To get such an entry edit `Info-debug.plist` in Xcode, click the `+` button to add a new line to the plist file, paste in `NSBonjourServices` and press enter. This will then turn into a list as in the screenshot and you can paste `_dartoversvator._tcp` as the first item as in the screenshot).

Don't forget to keep `Info-debug.plist` up to date with `Info.plist` if you make changes to it.